# How to put a counter in Group By Customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

They're the same column

```
Name-Category
A-SL
B-SL
C-SL
A-SL
A-SL
C-SL
```

now in my script, i group them in Category but i want to count on how many times they occur in the query. please see below:

```
Customer-Line#
A-1 (means its the first time it occurs)
A-2 (means its the second time it occurs)
A-3 (means its the third time it occurs)
....so on
----------
B-1 (means its the first time it occurs)
----------
C-1 (means its the first time it occurs)
C-2 (means its the second time it occurs)
```

sorry for confusion, hope its clear for everyone.

Thank you,

Comment: Read about [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) window function

Comment: Could you provide us with some sample data, table structures etc? Also, do you necessarily want to do this via stored procedures and not a select query?

Comment: @cha could you provide the example of ROW_NUMBER() your referring to?

Comment: @CodeNewbie, its fine only select statement. i can do the SP after.

Comment: Then please provide sample data. On what basis does A go from 1 to 3, while B only goes to 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`row_number()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to add a number to customers with the same name:

```
select  name + '-' + cast(row_number() over (
            partition by name order by id) as varchar(24))
from    YourTable
```

If the number is only required if there is more than one customer, you can use a [`case when ... then ... end`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression:

```
select  name + 
            case 
            when count(*) over (partition by name) = 1 then ''
            else '-' + cast(row_number() over (
                partition by name order by id) as varchar(24))
            end
from    YourTable
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f6e79/1/0)

Comment: sorry, i didn't on this earlier. but it works though!
Thank you!